# How to improve accuracy of calculating eigenvalues of Non-Hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a non-Hermitian Matrix `nonHM` whose size is $n \times n$ and is a function of $c1$.the `Eigenvalues` are symmetric with respect to $c1$, i.e. $E(c1)=E(-c1)$, however, MMA gives correct results only for small $n$ but we lose the symmetry for large $n$ which is expected (not sure!) to be a matter of accuracy? So, how can increase the accuracy?

here I am calculating the imaginary part of the eigenvalues

```
org = c1 PauliMatrix[1] + I c2/2 PauliMatrix[2];
cp = 1/2 (PauliMatrix[1]  + I PauliMatrix[2]);
nonHM[n_] := 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {2 n, 2 n}] -> {org}, 
   Band[{1, 3}, {2 n, 2 n}] -> {cp}, 
   Band[{3, 1}, {2 n, 2 n}] -> {ConjugateTranspose[cp]}}]
c2 = 4/3; sizn = 40;
Eign0 = ParallelTable[{c1, Eigenvalues[N@nonHM[sizn]]}, {c1, -3, 3, 
    0.01}];
listIm = Table[{-3 + 0.01 i, Im[Eign0[[i]][[2, j]]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[Eign0]}, {j, 1, 2 sizn}];
ListPlot[Transpose[listIm], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"c1", "ImE"}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black}, 
 PlotRange -> {-0.8, 0.8}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Small]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

this is for $n=5$

[image]

and for $n=40$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rationalize `.01` in the lines `Eign0=...` and `listIm=...`:

To get finite evaluation time I decreased the increment `{c1, -3, 3,1/10  }`

```
Eign0 = ParallelTable[{c1, Eigenvalues[nonHM[sizn] ]}, {c1, -3, 3,1/10  }];
```

In the next line index `i` must be replaced by `i-1` I think.

```
listIm = Table[{-3 + 1/10  (i-1), Im[Eign0[[i]][[2,j]]]}, {i, 1,Length[Eign0]}, {j, 1, 2 sizn}];

ListPlot[Transpose[listIm], Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"c1", "ImE"}, LabelStyle ->{FontSize -> 18, Black}, PlotRange -> {-0.8, 0.8}, Axes -> True,PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Small]],AspectRatio -> 1,ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: it takes too long and is not finished?! I am using MMA 12.3.0 on win64

Comment: @valarmorghulis See my modified answer. I decreased the discretisation of `c1` to get finite evaluation time.

Comment: thanks for the help!  correct $(i-1)$ but this way it becomes time expensive!

Comment: Using `Eigenvalues[N[nonHM[sizn], 30]]` is faster than calculating analytical Eigenvalues and also more accurate.